# How to read and write an object to a text file in java?

Tags: java, object, serialization, file-io, deserialization

I have an array of objects and I want to write them in a text file. So that I can later read the objects back in an array. How should I do it?
**Using Serialization.**

Deserialization is not working:

```
public static void readdata(){
        ObjectInputStream input = null;
        try {
            input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("myfile.txt")); // getting end of file exception here
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            array = (players[]) input.readObject(); // null pointer exception here
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        readdata();
        writedata();
    }
```

Comment: read about serialization and apply ..

Comment: Having problem in reading file. writing is working.

Comment: Surely you can be more specific than "not working"? Is an exception thrown? If so, what's the stacktrace?

Comment: exceptions are thrown in try catch, i have wrote the exception in the comment see after the line.

Comment: Wrap the array in another object

Comment: @Shivam did you try wrapping the array in another object as i suggested? i didn't test it but i'm pretty sure it works

Comment: Serialized data is not text. Your exception handling is poorly structured, which is the cause of all your problems. Code that depends once success of code in a try block should be inside the same try block. You can't get both end of file and a null pointer exception at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

The process of converting objects into strings and vice versa is called Serialization and Deserialization. In order to serialize an object it should implement `Serializable` interface. Most built-in data types and data structures are serializable by default, only certain classes are not serializable (for example `Socket` is not serializable).

So first of all you should make your class Serializable:

```
 class Student implements java.io.Serializable {
     String name;
     String studentId;
     float gpa;
     transient String thisFieldWontBeSerialized;
 }
```

The you can use `ObjectOutputStream` to serialize it and write to a file:

```
public class Writer {
    static void writeToFile(String fileName, Student[] students) throws IOException {
        File f = new File(fileName);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f));
        oos.writeObject(students);
        oos.flush();
        oos.close();
    }
}
```

`ObjectInputStream` can be used in a similar way to read the array back from file.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Java doesn't give you an easy way to do this for arbitrary objects. Thus, consider restricting yourself to an array of `Serializable`.

If the objects you have to handle are of your own classes and you thus want these classes to implement the `java.io.Serializable` interface, carefully read what ['contract' it comes with](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/io/Serializable.html), as not all of what you have to guarantee for your class will be enforced programatically at compile-time. (So if your classes implement `Serializable` without completely following the conditions it poses, you might get runtime errors or just 'wrong' and maybe hard-to-detect runtime behavior.)

(See also these [best practices](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=45).)

Comment: I am getting endoffile exception and nullpointer exception

ObjectInputStream input = null;
input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("myfile.txt")); // end of file here
array = (players[]) input.readObject(); // null pointer here

whats wrong here

Comment: Code in comments isn't really legible. Consider editing it into your question or to ask a new question with it if appropriate.